# Cannot update dependency package with godeps

Tags: go, stripe-payments, godeps

I need to update stripe-go library version.
Project has 19.**
New version 52.**
There is a godeps dependency manager

When I try to run

> godep save github.com/stripe/stripe-go

I get

> godep: cannot save github.com/stripe/stripe-go/form at revision
>   f8b095462d541c43d981d28de52b7464b25f3ee1: already have
>   github.com/stripe/stripe-go at revision
>   87c04229ff0262e4e7dfc8af7dc97a471e955ba2.
>
> Run `godep update github.com/stripe/stripe-go' first.

And when I run

> godep update github.com/stripe/stripe-go

I get

> godep: no packages can be updated

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember this issue, quoting from https://github.com/tools/godep/issues/164#issuecomment-101345584

> This seems to be caused by this line here:
>   https://github.com/tools/godep/blob/master/update.go#L205
>
> If packages A and B are under the same root, and I try to only update
>   B, the root will be marked for skipping update because A isn't being
>   updated. I'm not sure what the motivation for this feature is, it
>   seems that developers should be able to selectively update sub
>   packages as they desire.
>
> For what it's worth, I fixed my problem by globbing from the root in
>   my godep update command (e.g. godep update github.com/foo/bar/...
>   instead of github.com/foo/bar/pkg/B. A helpful error message would
>   have gone a long way

While you're here, go 1.11 and above has inbuilt module support. Maybe look into shifting into that? https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules

Comment: I cannot change go version. What if remove old dependencies packages form videos.json manually? and try run godeps save ?

Comment: could you add the json, so I can help you better? @b3lowster

Comment: Would be enough if I share JSON file but only with Stripe dependencies?

Comment: @b3lowster Yeah that should be sufficient! `cat something.json | grep -i stripe`.

Comment: cat Godeps/Godeps.json | grep -i stripe
"ImportPath": "github.com/stripe/stripe-go",
"ImportPath": "github.com/stripe/stripe-go/card",
"ImportPath": "github.com/stripe/stripe-go/charge",
"ImportPath": "github.com/stripe/stripe-go/customer",
"ImportPath": "github.com/stripe/stripe-go/orderitem",
"ImportPath": "github.com/stripe/stripe-go/token",

Comment: if i try to run : godep update github.com/stripe/..
I get: godep: not in manifest: github.com
godep: no packages can be updated

Comment: It work for this command :) godep update github.com/stripe/...    Thanks a lot

Comment: @b3lowster that's awesome! do accept my answer as the solution.

Comment: What if I need to add one more submodel for instance github.com/stripe/stripe-go/payout what should I do? Project didn't have this module before

Comment: @b3lowster `dep ensure <pkg>` should do it. Check here https://golang.github.io/dep/docs/daily-dep.html#using-dep-ensure. Basically when updating you'll face problems again, so the same solution would apply.